# Laravel S3 Image upload returning 503 error on FortRabbit

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5, image-uploading, http-status-code-503, fortrabbit

Using Laravel and its storage facade to assist with image uploads on my website.

I currently have it set up and working fine using dropzone.js and uploading to my s3 bucket.

However, when pushing it to FortRabbit the image uploads receive a 503 error. I can delete resources from s3 however.

This is the response as previewed in the network tab:

[image]

I have contacted FortRabbit but seems nothing on their end is broken. Just odd it works locally and not on there.

Bit stuck on where to go / debug this one.

Answer (score 0):

To further investigate what's going on, one can look in the [logs](https://help.fortrabbit.com/logging) for errors like so:

`ssh {{ssh-user}}@log.{{region}}.frbit.com tail`

Sorry, this is not a good question for Stack Overflow. It's too specific.